# Why is my RxJava subscription in unit test lost without being disposed

Tags: java, unit-testing, rx-java2

I am trying to write a unit test for my view model based on RxJava. In production it runs fine but in my unit test one of my subscriptions is lost without dispose or anything ever being called.

I am using the MVI pattern. All classes (Intent, Action, Result, ViewState) just have a text for simplicity reasons.

```
public class ViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = ViewModel.class.getSimpleName();
    private final ISchedulerProvider schedulerProvider;
    private Observable<ViewState> viewState;
    private PublishSubject<Intent> intentEmitter = PublishSubject.create();
    private IActionProcessHolder<Action, Result> actionProcessHolder;

    public ViewModel(ISchedulerProvider schedulerProvider, IActionProcessHolder actionProcessHolder){
        this.schedulerProvider = schedulerProvider;
        this.actionProcessHolder = actionProcessHolder;
        viewState = compose();
    }

    private Observable<ViewState> compose() {
        return intentEmitter
                .compose(getIntentToActionTransformer())
                .compose(actionProcessHolder.getActionProcessor())
                .map(result -> new ViewState(result.getText()));
    }

    public void processIntents(Observable<Intent> intent){
        intent
                .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                .observeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                .subscribe(
                        anIntent -> intentEmitter.onNext(anIntent),
                        error -> Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage())
                );
    }

    public Observable<ViewState> getViewState(){
        return viewState;
    }

    private ObservableTransformer<Intent, Action> getIntentToActionTransformer(){
        return intent ->
                intent.map(theIntent -> new Action(theIntent.getText()));
    }
}
```

```
public class ATestScheduler implements ISchedulerProvider {

    @Override
    public Scheduler computation() { return Schedulers.trampoline(); }

    @Override
    public Scheduler io() { return Schedulers.trampoline(); }

    @Override
    public Scheduler ui() { return Schedulers.trampoline(); }
}
```

```
public class Intent {
    String text;
    public Intent(String text){ this.text = text; }
    public String getText(){ return text; }
}
```

```
public class ActionProcessHolder implements IActionProcessHolder<Action,Result>{
    @Override
    public ObservableTransformer<Action,Result> getActionProcessor(){
        return action -> action.map(theAction -> new Result(theAction.getText()));
    }
}
```

```
public class ViewModelTest {

    @Mock
    private ObservableTransformer<Action, Result> actionProcessor;
    @Mock
    private IActionProcessHolder<Action, Result> actionProcessHolder;
    private TestObserver<ViewState> testObserver;
    private ViewModel viewModel;
    private CompositeDisposable subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable();

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ISchedulerProvider schedulerProvider = new ATestScheduler();
        testObserver = new TestObserver<>();

        when(actionProcessHolder.getActionProcessor()).thenReturn(actionProcessor);
        when(actionProcessor.apply(any())).thenReturn(Observable.just(new Result("mocked text")));

        viewModel = new ViewModel(schedulerProvider, actionProcessHolder);
        subscriptions.add(viewModel.getViewState()
            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
            .subscribe(
                    viewState -> testObserver.onNext(viewState)
                    , error -> Assert.fail(error.getMessage())));
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessIntent(){
        viewModel.processIntents(Observable.just(new Intent("newText")));
        testObserver.assertValueAt(0, viewState -> viewState.getText().equals("mocked text"));
        verify(actionProcessor, times(2)).apply(any());
    }
```

I am expecting the actionProcessor to be called twice, once during initialization and once when I process another intent in the actual test. However when the intent is processed, the intentEmitter in the view model no longer has any subscribers, so onNext does nothing.

I have worked out that the line in the ViewModel class:

> .compose(actionProcessHolder.getActionProcessor())

seems to break it. When i simply map my action to a result like this:

> .map(action -> new Result(action.getText()))

(the same the actionProcessor should do) the subscription is not disposed.
I have set breakpoints everywhere the subscriptions are disposed but none of them are ever called.
Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually not that the subscription is disposed but the chain of subscriptions is never established.
During the setup, when subscribe is called, with this line

> when(actionProcessor.apply(any())).thenReturn(Observable.just(new Result("mocked text")));

Mockito immediately caused the Observable to emit its value and broke the subscription process.
I solved it now by mocking the actionProcessor without using Mockito, simply substituting above line with this:

> actionProcessor = action -> action.map(ignore -> new Result("mocked text"));